# Text in Bootstrap's btn-check label is not aligned middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a list of checkboxes with btn-check. Some of their labels are long, others are short. I would like to have all the labels aligned middle. However, I haven't been able to find a way to do this. In the screenshot below, the first box shows the problem. The content is not in the middle of the box.

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap w-100 h-100">
          <input type="checkbox" id="b" class="btn-check" value="b">
          <!-- This label has the problem -->
          <label for="b" class="btn btn-outline-primary align-middle ">
                <span class="text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor<br><small class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</small></span>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap w-100 h-100">
          <input type="checkbox" id="a" class="btn-check" value="a">
          <label for="a" class="btn btn-outline-primary ">
                <span class="text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br><small class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum </small></span>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Does somebody know what I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution 1**

just add `d-flex align-items-center` following class in

```
<label for="b" class="btn btn-outline-primary align-middle ">
```

so it will be `<label for="b" class="btn btn-outline-primary align-middle d-flex align-items-center">` also in `<label for="a" .../>`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap w-100 h-100">
          <input type="checkbox" id="b" class="btn-check" value="b">
          <!-- This label has the problem -->
          <label for="b" class="btn btn-outline-primary align-middle d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor<br><small class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</small></span>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap w-100 h-100">
          <input type="checkbox" id="a" class="btn-check" value="a">
          <label for="a" class="btn btn-outline-primary d-flex align-items-center">
                <span class="text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br><small class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum </small></span>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

**solution 2**

also you can wrap span tag in div and label code will be look like following

```
<label for="b" class="btn btn-outline-primary align-middle ">
   <div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100">
      <span class="text-break">Lorem ipsum dolor<br><small class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</small></span>
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working :) I also added w-100 to the label, and then I had to add justify-content-center to center the text